# SQL Server : how to insert and set of data into a new table by using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I quite new to SQL Server and need your help about how to run this table from row data to column data by using day calculation on each month during each periods.

The problem is I want to calculate day used in each month and money spent by month on each period as below.

Table: `Spent_Info`

Structure:

```
- Name
- Start_Date (datetime)
- End_Date (datetime)
- Total_Amount_spent
```

Data of table `Spent_Info`:

```
John  between 28/6/2014 9:00:00 and  2/8/2014 10:00:00 spent 500 USD
Marry between 16/6/2014 9:00:00 and 20/8/2014 10:00:00 spent 900 USD
```

Expected result:

Table: `temp_Spent_Info_detail` (This is a blank table, I want to insert data that calculated as below condition into this table)

Structure:

```
- Name
- Start_Date (datetime)
- End_Date (datetime)
- Total_Amount_spent
- Total_Day_Spent
- Month
- Year
- Total_spent_day_in_month
- Month_Amount_Spent
```

Data of table `temp_Spent_Info_detail`:

```
John  between 28/6/2014 9:00:00 and  2/8/2014 10:00:00 spent 500 USD total ___ days
Marry between 16/6/2014 9:00:00 and 20/8/2014 10:00:00 spent 900 USD total ___ days
```

---

```
John  between 28/6/2014 9:00:00 and 30/6/2014 23:59:59 spent ____ USD total ____ (days) on 6 (Month) 2014 (Year)
John  between 01/7/2014 00:00:00 and 31/7/2014 23:59:59 spent ____ USD total 31 (days) on 7 (Month) 2014 (Year) 
John  between 01/8/2014 00:00:00 and 2/8/2014 10:00:00 spent ____ USD total ___ (days) on 8 (Month) 2014 (Year) 
Marry  between 16/6/2014 9:00:00 and 30/6/2014 23:59:59 spent ____ USD total ____ (days) on 6 (Month) 2014 (Year)
...
```

....

---

Hereunder is my code

```
DECLARE 

@vsid int, @vc varchar, @vn int, @oh varchar, @sg DATETIME, @eg
DATETIME, @dism float, @sm int, @sy int, @diem float, @em int, @ey
int, @sd float, @tce float;
```

Section 1: Get the list of data that I want to split the time period of each data to be day in month.

```
;with set_data (vsid, vc, vn, oh, sg, eg, dism, sm, sy, diem, em, ey, sd, tce) as
(
SELECT voypnl._sqlid as voypnl_id , upper(voypnl.vslCode) as v_code, upper(voypnl.vslName)as v_name, left (voypnl.oprType,2)as Own_Hire, 
voypnl.commencingGmt , voypnl.completedGmt ,
CASE when  (month(voypnl.commencingGmt) = month(voypnl.completedGmt)) then  round(datediff(minute,(voypnl.commencingGmt),(voypnl.completedGmt))/1440.0,2) else round(datediff(minute,(voypnl.commencingGmt),((DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,voypnl.commencingGmt)+1,0)) )))/1440.0,2)  end  as DayInStartMonth,
month(voypnl.commencingGmt) AS start_Month,
Year(voypnl.commencingGmt) AS start_Year,
case when (month(voypnl.commencingGmt) = month(voypnl.completedGmt)) then 0 else (round(datediff(minute,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,voypnl.completedGmt),0),(voypnl.completedGmt))/1440.0,2)) end as DayInEndMonth, 
month(voypnl.completedGmt) AS end_Month,
Year(voypnl.completedGmt) AS end_Year,
round(datediff(minute,(voypnl.commencingGmt),(voypnl.completedGmt))/1440.0,2) as ServiceDay,
round(voypnl.tcEquv,2) as total_TCE

FROM [test_V508_tes].[dbo].[voypnl] as voypnl

WHERE(voypnl.vslCode <> 'XXXX') AND (voypnl.vslCode <> 'ONBD') 
AND (voypnl.data_type = 'A') and (year(voypnl.commencingGmt) between 2012 and 2020);
) ,
```

Section 2: I want to use below code / any recommended code to split the time period of each data to be day in month by retriving all data record from Section 1 and then insert into another table

```
r_number(n) AS
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @sg, @eg)+1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (ORDER BY [object_id])-1 FROM sys.all_objects
),
r_month(r_number,fd,ld) AS 
(
  SELECT r_number.n, DATEADD(MONTH, r_number.n, month_start.m), DATEADD(MONTH, r_number.n+1, month_start.m)
  FROM r_number, (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@sg), @sg)) AS month_start(m)
)


SELECT [Month] = MONTH(fd), [Days] = DATEDIFF(day, fd, ld)
  - CASE WHEN @sg > fd THEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, fd, @sg)+1) ELSE 0 END
  - CASE WHEN @eg < ld THEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, @eg, ld)-1) ELSE 0 END

FROM r_month;
```

Comment: So, you want us to write the entire thing for you, is that correct? Or do you want us to help you with a specific part of your problem? Have you tried something already and, if so, could you share what you have tried?

Comment: I am too, to be honest. In your `Spent_Info` data sample, John's interval is `between 16/6/2014 9:00:00 and 20/8/2014 10:00:00` and in `temp_Spent_Info_detail` it's `between 28/6/2014 9:00:00 and 2/8/2014 10:00:00`. Typo? The length of the latter interval is 35.04 days but you show it as 35.75. Another typo? I *think* I can see what you are trying to do, but consistent examples would help me to be sure, because if my guess happened to be incorrect, I'd just be wasting my time trying to come up with a solution for you.

Comment: So sorry, I type wrong. Please see the revised one. Thank you